# woocommerce: how to add new fields to variations form and show them on frontend

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

using last versions of wordpress, woocommerce and cheope (theme).
the question: how to

1. add some extra fields in variations form (text and image field types)
2. show them on frontend so that their values change accordingly on changing of attributes-select values.

e.g.: the site sells candles and uses variable products, for each kind of candle has several dimensions (with specific different prices), each of which has different duration.
The duration is an important element that I want the user to be informed about.
The same to show the available colors all together.
Unluckily in the standard variation form there is no field where I can insert these or other features.
some help please?

updated 07-August-2013
I succeeded in adding to variations form a new field displayed on back-end, as you can see [here](http://www.mayerweb.it/mycustomfield_snapshot.jpg), by inserting  the code you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/kloon/4228021) (please see the comments too) in the function.php file of the theme.
Now, what I’m not able to do is get this field to display with each proper value on front-end (please take a look to the last comment in the above linked page).
Any tip or trick?
thanks

Comment: you can try this using woocommerce variable product, and to get two extra fields in product detail page, woocommerce provide you option to add some custom fields in your project with little use of code to fetch those values and show in fronted, if this is useful for you i can help in code as well

Comment: thank you Balram for your reply and availability.
if I well understood the custom fields you refer to are those you can append to the parent of variations, instead I need them in the single children.
Actually I found out a snippet by which to add custom fields where I want, but I'm not able to show them on front-end.
If you are willing to take a look here:
[link](https://gist.github.com/kloon/4228021)
I'll be grateful.
bye
ruggero

Comment: Woocommerce itself provide option of custom field in add product page, you can uuse them and fetch those values in frontend, if your problem is not yet resolved, i can write code to fetch values of those custom fields provided by woocommerce

Comment: Hi Balram, thanks again for your interest, but the custom fields provided by woocommerce don’t do the job, or I cannot figure out how they could. please take a look to my above update and first link. hoping to read you again, ruggero.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add product attribute and check checkbox Used for variations and Visible on the product page
2)go to variations and add new and fill all fields price and stock must  add on them

Your producr display variations and their data